# Allegro Debug -Abort() Has Been Called

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, allegro

Eu tentei fazer uma animação e o Visual Studio dá o erro `Debug -Abort() Has Been Called`.

Código:

```c
#include <allegro5\allegro.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_native_dialog.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>

const int WIDTH = 1000;
const int HEIGHT = 600;
bool exit = false;

const int maxFrame = 12;
int curFrame = 0;
int frameCount = 0;
int frameDelay = 5;


int main()
{
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *event_queue = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_TIMER *timer;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image[maxFrame];

    if(!al_init())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    display = al_create_display(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    if(!display)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    al_install_keyboard;
    al_init_image_addon;

    image[0] = al_load_bitmap("walking w0000.bmp");
    image[1] = al_load_bitmap("walking w0001.bmp");
    image[2] = al_load_bitmap("walking w0002.bmp");
    image[3] = al_load_bitmap("walking w0003.bmp");
    image[4] = al_load_bitmap("walking w0004.bmp");
    image[5] = al_load_bitmap("walking w0005.bmp");
    image[6] = al_load_bitmap("walking w0006.bmp");
    image[7] = al_load_bitmap("walking w0007.bmp");
    image[8] = al_load_bitmap("walking w0008.bmp");
    image[9] = al_load_bitmap("walking w0009.bmp");
    image[10] = al_load_bitmap("walking w0010.bmp");
    image[11] = al_load_bitmap("walking w0011.bmp");

    for(int i = 0; i < maxFrame; i++)
    {
        al_convert_mask_to_alpha(image[i], al_map_rgb(106, 76, 48));
    }

    event_queue = al_create_event_queue();
    timer = al_create_timer(1.0 / 60);

    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_timer_event_source(timer));
    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_keyboard_event_source());

    al_start_timer(timer);

    while(!exit)
    {
        ALLEGRO_EVENT ev;
        al_wait_for_event(event_queue, &ev);

        if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN)
        {
            switch(ev.keyboard.keycode)
            {
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE:
                exit = true;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_LEFT:

                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_RIGHT:

                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_UP:

                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_DOWN:

                break;
            }
        }
        else if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER)
        {
            if(++frameCount >= frameDelay)
            {
                if(++curFrame >= maxFrame)
                {
                    curFrame = 0;
                }
                frameCount = 0;
            }
        }

        al_draw_bitmap(image[curFrame], 200, 100, 0);

        al_flip_display();
        al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0)); 

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < maxFrame; i++)
    {
        al_destroy_bitmap(image[i]);
    }
    al_destroy_event_queue(event_queue);
    al_destroy_display(display);

    return 0;
}
```

Erro completo:

```
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Lucas-PC\Desktop\Arquivos\Sobrevivencia\Debug\Sobrevivencia.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\allegro-5.0.10-monolith-md-debug.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.9600.17415_none_dad8722c5bcc2d8f\GdiPlus.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.9600.17810_none_7c5b6194aa0716f1\comctl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\aticfx32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiu9pag.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiu9pag.dll'
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiu9pag.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiumdag.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiumdva.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Download Manager\idmmkb.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Sobrevivencia.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Sobrevivencia.exe has triggered a breakpoint
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x14c0) has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xcfc) has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x17e0) has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x140c) has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x804) has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The program '[4472] Sobrevivencia.exe: Native' has exited with code 3 (0x3).
```

Comment: As mensagens `Cannot find or open the PDB file` provavelmente não são importantes. A parte que importa acho que é a partir do `Sobrevivencia.exe has triggered a breakpoint`.

Comment: Imagina oque pode ser ??

Comment: Euu não sei. Talvez alguém que saiba venha aqui...

Answer (score 2):

O primeiro erro está na inclusão dos arquivos do Allegro 5:

```
#include <allegro5\allegro.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_native_dialog.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>
```

Você está utilizando erroneamente o '\' para incluir os dois primeiros arquivos. Use '/' no lugar de '\' quando se referir a arquivos. (Se quiser saber o motivo para isso, basicamente '\' é um caractere especial em C e C++ que realiza diversas operações com strings, por isso ele é evitado.)

Seu segundo erro está na falta de inicialização dos addons que você incluiu. Sempre, **sempre** que for fazer qualquer programa com Allegro 5, inicialize seus arquivos. No caso os arquivos que precisam de inicialização são o `allegro.h` e o `allegro_image.h`. Para inicializar o `allegro.h`, ponha no começo do programa o seguinte macro:

```
int main() {
     al_init();
```

Para inicializar o allegro_image.h, ponha **após** o `al_init()` a seguinte função:

```
     al_init_image_addon();
```

O último erro do seu programa se refere à falta de referência ao Allegro 5 e suas DLLs no Visual Studio. Para resolver esse problema, clique com o botão direito no seu projeto do Visual Studio, vá em propriedades, depois selecione *Configuration Properties>>Linker>>Input*, e no campo "*Additional Dependencies*" insira o nome da sua biblioteca atual (no caso suponho que você queira que seja uma versão de debug da biblioteca), ou seja: "*allegro-5.x.x-monolith-md-debug.lib*" (Substitua o "x.x" pela sua versão de Allegro 5. A minha por exemplo é 5.0.10).

**Edição:** Outro erro gravíssimo que você cometeu foi:

```
al_install_keyboard;
al_init_image_addon;
```

Você esqueceu de ***adicionar os parênteses*** após os nomes das funções. O compilador vai achar que você está querendo dizer outra coisa ao simplesmente por o nome da função no código. A maneira correta é:

```
al_install_keyboard();
al_init_image_addon();
```

Corrigidos estes erros, é quase certo que seu programa funcionará.